# Backing up to FTP server takes 8 hours

Tags: 11.10, backup, ftp, deja-dup

When trying to backup using deja dup to an FTP server, I find it takes about eight hours to backup what little I have in my home directory. This is a laptop, and so I have only had the time to have it make one complete backup. This worries me and I would like to have it upload faster. Is there some setting I can change to make it go faster? I'm already running low on  Ubuntu One space and want cloud backup. Any suggestions?

Comment: Upload speed is usually a small fraction speed of download speed. What is your upload speed? You can go to a site like speedtest.net to check it.

Comment: My upload speed is 0.82 mbps, 11.9 for download.

Comment: You are looking at about 3 hours per Gigabyte backed up at that upload speed. That assumes it stays constant and you aren't using the connection for anything else. More info here: http://www.dslreports.com/calculator?sz=1GB&time=&c2=Calc&speed=.82+Mbps&savestate=

Comment: Could you make this an answer so I can mark this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check your **upload** bandwidth/speed somewhere like [Speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net/)
2. Calculate your upload time by inputting your total amount of data and your upload speed into a bandwidth calculator, one is here at [dslreports.com](http://www.dslreports.com/calculator)

You are looking at about 3 hours per Gigabyte backed up at that upload speed. That assumes it stays constant and you aren't using the connection for anything else. I've already entered the values for your connection speed, with one Gigabyte of data, that link is [here](http://www.dslreports.com/calculator?sz=1%20GB&time=1249%20s&c2=Calc&speed=0.82%20Mbps&savestate=).

This is a common problem with asynchronous connections like home ADSL. The more data you want to send into the 'cloud', the more this becomes an issue. Some services like [Amazon's S3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3) allow you to [mail a hard drive](http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/) to them so you don't have to spend weeks uploading. It's not cheap though.

Answer (score 0):

One of the wonderful "backup" solutions I've run across that minimizes transfer time is borg backup.

It is a deduplicating solution so not only do the minimal amount of files get sent (like incremental backup) but the destination storage size is also minimized as it is deduplicated.

It is a command line utility which may a nonstarter for you, however I can't sing it enough praise:
https://github.com/borgbackup/borg